# Multi-output Time Series Forecasting with LSTMs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I'm building CNN-LSTM models for solar power production forecasting for multiple countries in the EU. My data is a time series with the target -> power production, and some features like weather conditions. I'm using data for past 24 hours to predict the next 24 hours. I'm using tensorflow datasets, and the shape of my data is like this:

```
x =  (64, 24, 4)
y =  (64, 24, 1)
```

Here's how the model looks like in general.

```
def get_model(window_size, n_features):
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64,
                                kernel_size=6,
                                strides=1,
                                padding="causal",
                                activation="relu",
                                input_shape=[window_size, n_features]),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, recurrent_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-2,l2=1e-2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.3),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, recurrent_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-2,l2=1e-2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.3),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(24,activation="relu")
        ])
    
  # Print the model summary
  model.summary()
  
  model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4), metrics=["mae"])
  
  
  return model
```

Now, my problem is that I want to build a joint model for 2 countries and I have no idea how to modify the model to predict 2 parallel time series. Now the shape of my data is like this:

```
x =  (64, 24, 8)
y =  (64, 24, 2)
```

I've tried to look for solutions on the internet but I only found solutions that I couldn't understand or answers based on modifying the output layer of the model which I think doesn't solve my problem.

Do you guys have any suggestions on solving my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its unclear how adding an additional country to your input data makes the shape of the data go from `(batch, 24, 4)` -> `(2 * batch, 24, 34)`.

Comment: If you current `x` for one country is `(32, 24, 4)`, then I would stack the two countries on the feature axis, that is `(32, 24, 8)`

Comment: You just explained how your dataset could go from (32, 24, 4) -> (32, 24, 8). That still does not explain how the data went from (32, 24, 4) -> (64, 24, 34)

Comment: Yes sorry, it is a mistake the data is like this, (batch, 24, 4) -> (batch, 24, 8) and I did stack the countries on the feature axis, but I have no idea how to deal with the output like this (batch, 24, 2).

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to predict two countries at the same time? As in, assume that you have N countries that you want to predict; stacking them along the feature access is going to get incredibly cumbersome. Why not make the name of the country a feature in your network. As in, use a combination of [StringLookup](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/StringLookup) and [Embedding](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) to feature-ize the country.